# css sibling with another element between selectors

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table, and when you press a cell it changes its color:

**HTML**

```
<table id="hours">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkHourR01C01" />
        <label for="checkHourR01C01"> </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  ...
```

**CSS**

```
table#hours input[type=checkbox] { visibility: hidden; }
table#hours input[type=checkbox]:checked  + label { background-color: blue; }
```

This worked perfect. The problem now is I´m working with ASP MVC 3, and Html.CheckboxFor adds antoher inputy type hidden. So my html structure is like:

**HTML**

```
<table id="hours">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected field is required." id="Days_0__Hours_0__Selected" name="Days[0].Hours[0].Selected" type="checkbox" value="true" />
        <input name="Days[0].Hours[0].Selected" type="hidden" value="false" />
        <label for="Days_0__Hours_0__Selected"> </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  ...
```

So now is like:

```
table#hours input[type=checkbox]:checked input[type=hidden] + label { background-color: blue; }
```

But this doesn´t work. Is there any way fix it with CSS, or I need to change to jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `~` [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

```
table#hours input[type=checkbox]:checked input[type=hidden] ~ label { background-color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`label` is still a sibling of the `checkbox` it's just not adjacent. Try your original CSS except use `~` instead of `+`.

```
table#hours input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ label { background-color: blue; }
```